# Show Interfaces in ArgoUml Sequence diagram

Tags: java, uml, argouml

I am using ArgoUml to draw sequence diagram. But how can i show interface classes along with the implementation using ArgoUML?

Answer (score 0):

A `ClassifierRole` can have either an `Interface` or a `Class` associated with it, since they're both subtypes of `Classifier`.  Just drag the classes or interfaces that you want to work with onto the Sequence Diagram and start drawing Actions between them.